# Report showing no results in Lightning for "My Opportunities"

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting

I am baffled by this one:

Exact same report... first in Classic:

[image]

Then in lightning:

[image]

No filters except to show "my opportunities"

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you accessing the report in lightning Salesforce?

Comment: It looks like you're [filtering by role](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_role_hierarchy.htm&type=5) (as the "VP Revenue" role) in the Classic screenshot.  Are you doing the same in the Lightning view? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_role_hierarchy.htm&type=5